# Can't get data from Django View into template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to send some data for rendering a table in a template. The data is not a `QuerySet` or anything, it's a custom list of tuples that I get from a Django Rest Framework endpoint.

I have the following view:

```
class GetPointsView(FormView):
    form_class = forms.GetPointsForm
    template_name = 'get_points.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('get_points')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        var = request.POST['var_field']
        if form.is_valid():
            # Call another view to get the data, based on 'var'.
            response = MyView().get(request, var)
            # The template never handles this data.
            data = json.loads(response.data)
            # And even this doesn't work...
            # data = [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'guido')]
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                self.get_success_url(),
                {'mydata': data}
            )
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

And the following template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% crispy form %}

    {% if mydata %}
    <hr>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Col A</th>
            <th>Col B</th>
        </tr>
        {% for cola, colb in mydata %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ cola }}</td>
            <td>{{ colb }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`{% if mydata %}}` appears never to be true. The fact that `data = [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'guido')]` does not even work, suggests I'm missing something here.

Am I doing something wrong with the format of the data, or how I'm sending it to the template?

---

**Edit with answer**

So, although I tried Django's `render` shortcut before, I was only able to get it working now. This is what solved my problem:

```
return render(self.request,
              self.template_name,
              {'form': form, 'mydata': data})
```

Comment: change {% if data %}} to {% if  mydata %}.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you shouldn't override the post model. The only thing you are customising is inside the is_valid block; so just out that into a `form_valid()` method.

Comment: @Aki003, Sorry, {%if data %} was a typo when I anonymized the question. Removing the extra } didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, my code all of a sudden looks a lot DRYer. :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Do one thing, just dump the output of  {{mydata}} and check if its showing anything not, maybe you can put a image link. I debug this way.

Comment: @Aki003 It appears to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

The key in your rendering context is 'mydata', so you should use `{% if mydata %}`. Also you have an extra `}` at the end of that line.

Comment: Sorry, `{%if data %}` was a typo when I anonymized the question. Removing the extra `}` didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Well, now that is out of the way. You are passing your data as an argument to a redirect. And then you are trying to access it from a template. Templates need to be rendered with context, otherwise your data just gets lost somewhere along the way (not sure how extra arguments are handled by HttpResponse class). So you need to make an actual template object using get_template() and render it with your data in the context. Try that.

Comment: Update the code to return rendered template instead of redirect and we can figure out where to go from there.

Comment: OK, I tried rendering the template. "VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [form] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {'points_data': [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'guido')]}]"". So, the data is there, but since I'm trying to combine a form and a table on a single page, it raised.

Comment: Can you update the code, so I can see what you are trying?

Comment: See my question, I solved it. Don't know what went wrong with `render` initially...

Comment: Great. I hope I helped a bit.